# Which source code formatter is being used in react-admin?

Tags: visual-studio-code, react-admin, prettier-vscode

I cloned the source code of react-admin from https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin.

When I tried formatting the source code by VS Code (Windows) with "Prettier - Code formatter" or "TypeScript and Javascript Language Features", the source code is formatted differently with the current format of react-admin source code.

Which source code formatter are they using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using eslint with prettier, but with a specific config:

- https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/.eslintrc
- https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/.prettierrc.js

You should configure your editor to read the project-specific configuration for these tools.